# Local Wi-Fi network without internet for Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, networking, wifi, dhcp

I have a web application which will be connected with some mobiles devices. The problem is that the application will be deployed in a Raspberry Pi 3 without internet connection.

So, I am trying to create a local Wi-Fi network to solve this problem.

I have seen this tutorial: [How-To: Turn a Raspberry Pi into a WiFi router](http://raspberrypihq.com/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-wifi-router/) but it is necessary an Ethernet connection.

Is there a way to create/enable a local Wi-Fi connection between a Raspberry Pi and mobile devices?

Comment: dalcala, I am trying to do the same thing.. but the given link from thewaywewere is no longer available. Do you have some more detail steps to share ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post [Using your new Raspberry Pi 3 as a WiFi access point with hostapd](https://web.archive.org/web/20190623082555/https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/) will guide you setting up a local access point for connecting WiFi enabled devices directly to Pi 3.

Below is the 2 major software components used.

> **hostapd** - This is the package that allows you to use the built in WiFi
> as an access point
>  **dnsmasq** - This is a combined DHCP and DNS
> server that's very easy to configure

There are 4 key steps to get it being setup.

1. Configure your wlan0 interface
2. Configure hostapd (host access point daemon)
3. Config dnsmasq
4. Setup IPv4 packet forwarding

Hope this help.

Comment: My project works as expected after following the post. Thank you very much!

Comment: @dalcala You are welcome!